# Download zip from github and bitbucket private repo in node

Tags: node.js, github, bitbucket, github-api

For gitlab I can download a private repo in node by simple using making an http request to:

```
"https://" + host + "/" + group + "/" + project + "/repository/archive.zip\?ref\=" + branch + "\&\private_token\=" + private_token;
```

Is this also possible for github and bitbucket?

I find a lot of curl scripts which use username and password to authenticate.

Can I also do this simply with a private token (as in gitlab)?

The repositories are private!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using the [GitHub Contents API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#get-archive-link). This The `/get-archive-link` resources will provide you a URL that you can then use `curl` to download the file.

> Can I also do this simply with a private token (as in gitlab)?

You can and you should. Generate a [personal access token](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-an-access-token-for-command-line-use/#creating-a-token) with [scope](https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/#scopes) `repo`.

There's several ways [to authenticate](https://developer.github.com/v3/#authentication) with the GitHub API. I personally prefer to use the HTTP authentication fields:

`https://USER@TOKEN:api.github.com/...`

Comment: Suggestion above helped to come up with my node one-liner to download a file from an enterprise git repo.  
await download(git_url_points_to_raw_file_without_token,  path_to_be_saved_file,  {auth: `${gitUser}:${gitToken}`}).   
download is from https://www.npmjs.com/package/download

Comment: @heatherz, I used your one liner it doesn't seem to work. Can you check and send the oneliner  that you have used. Thanks